# Is there a much easier way to find the vertices of a Eulerian Path?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

If I have a $K_8$ graph like the one [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJGTn.png)
and I want to label the Eulerian path for the vertices? what would be the best way to do this, there has to be a better way then just going through the lines one at a time. I keep getting lost every time... how do mathmaticians approach this?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Constructing_Eulerian_trails_and_circuits.

Answer (score 3):

**Euler path finding algorithm:**

STEP $1$: Locate the two vertices of odd degree. Pick one of them at random.

STEP $2$: Start walking from the chosen vertex. Make sure you don’t use the same edge
twice. Continue until you get stuck - this can only happen when you visit the other
odd-degree vertex and have used up every edge through it.

STEP $3$: Remove from $G$ all the edges you’ve walked along and let $G′$ be the remaining
subgraph. For each connected component of $G′$
, perform the Euler cycle finding algorithm.

STEP $4$: Glue together the hierarchy of walks so as to obtain an Euler path between the
two odd-degree vertices in the original graph $G$.

---

**Euler cycle finding algorithm:**

STEP $1$: Choose a starting vertex $v$ at random.

STEP $2$: Start walking from $v$. Make sure you don’t use the same edge twice. Continue
until you return to $v$ and have used up every edge through it.

STEP $3$: Remove from $G$ all the edges you’ve walked along and let $G′$ be the remaining
subgraph. For each connected component of $G′$
, go to Step $1$.

STEP $4$: Finally, when there are no edges left, glue together the hierarchy of walks so
as to obtain an Euler cycle in the original graph $G$.